# get mouse position on jquery.media object

Tags: javascript, jquery, mouse, media

I am trying to get the current mouse position in `javascript` with this simple sample code:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    console.log(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
});
```

This works fine but I want to get the current mouse position on elements like `<object>`. Namely I am using jQuery Media Plugin `jQuery.media.js` which generates the proper media element depending on the browser used. With [demos like this](http://jquery.malsup.com/media/video.html) the console stops logging as long as I stay on the media element. For instance I copy pasted this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.media.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.media').media();
});
$(document).mousemove(function(e){
    console.log(e.pageX +', '+ e.pageY);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <a class="media {width:480, height:280}" href="http://malsup.github.com/video/simpsons.mov">MOV File (video)</a> 
</body>
```

Can I use a different event? Or is this media element not part of `$(document)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DOM elements rendered by plugins are not standard DOM elements. They don't have to send any events to the browser. If it's a movie you are trying to display use HTML5 `<video>` tag - it should fire all standard DOM events correctly. If it's not an option, you may try putting a transparent `div` over the movie. It should fire all events correctly. The only drawback here is that the movie itself will not be clickable (controls etc.).

Comment: So you would recommend to let go of `jQuery.media.js` and use html5? Since I am using this tiny app just in my own environment this sounds like a neat solution! There should be a way to start playing the video instantly?

Comment: There is an `autoplay` attribute for the `video` tag which does exactly what you are looking for. Read more here: http://html5doctor.com/the-video-element/